# обработать ошибку в логе в пайплайне Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция, jenkins-pipeline

у меня есть следующий pipeline:

```
    pipeline {
    agent {
        label labelValue
    }
    
    stages {
        stage("Git") {
            steps {
                script {
                    git branch: "develop",
                            credentialsId: "xxx",
                            url: "https://"
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                withMaven(jdk: 'openjdk-12_linux') {
                    sh 'mvn clean compile assembly:single'
                }
            }
        }        
        
        stage("Run") {
            steps {
                withMaven(jdk: 'openjdk-12_linux', maven: 'Maven 3.6.3' {
                    sh 'java -jar SomethingName.jar ${par1} ${par2} ${par3} ${BUILD_URL}'
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Когда запускаю джарник с автотестом, то в случае ошибки, в логах есть текст "FAIL", а в случае успеха есть текст "SUCCESS". как через textFinder отловить нужный текст ("FAIL") и в случае ошибки - "свалить" джобу. Иначе все джобы зелененькие и успешные